# How to send content from cfdirectory in an email?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Below is my code. I need to send the `files.name[i]` in the content of the email. Please tell me how to do that? Give me a hint and I will try.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
        <html>
        <head>
            <script language="javascript" src="JS/jQuery.js"></script>
            <script>
                function page_refresh(){
                    document.getElementById('form2').action="project_file_dir.cfm"  
                    document.getElementById('form2').submit();          
                }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body >
        <cfoutput>
        <cfset fileLocation ="\\squeaker\SiSystemsFile\WebServices\WebSites\Perforce\Bhargavi"> <!--- On mac set to /tmp --->
        <cfdirectory
                action = "list"
                directory = "#fileLocation#"
                name = "files"
                filter="*.*">
        <form  method="post" id="form2">
            <cfset f="#files.recordcount#">  
            <cfset mydatetime=now()>
            <cfset a=TimeFormat(MyDateTime,'hh:mm:ss tt')>
              Total File in <b> #fileLocation# </b> Count is <b> #f# </b> #TimeFormat(MyDateTime,'hh:mm tt')#
               <input type="button" name="Refresh" value="refresh" onclick="page_refresh()"><br>
               <b>Next Run</b>
              <cfset b=TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', +5, MyDateTime),'hh:mm:ss tt')>
               #TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', +5, MyDateTime),'hh:mm tt')#
            </cfoutput>
            <!--- <cfset min_change= Minute(Now())>
            <cfset bin=min_change %5>
            <cfif bin eq 0>
                <cfinclude template="project_file_dir.cfm">
            </cfif> --->
            <cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = #f#>
            <cfoutput>
                #files.name[i]# <br>
            </cfoutput>
            </cfloop>
        </form>


        <cfmail to="Gayathri.p@sisystems.com"
            from="bhargavi.kumar@sisystems.com"
            subject="Testing the E-Mail"
            type="text">
            Dear Gayathri

                I just send this mail for testing . Please Ignore this 

            Regards
            Bhargavi
        </cfmail>
        <cfoutput>
            <p>Thank you  for registering.
            We have just sent you an email.</p>
        </cfoutput>


        <!--- <cffile action="write"
            addnewline="yes"
            file="\\squeaker\SiSystemsFile\WebServices\WebSites\Perforce\Bhargavi\report.txt" 
            output="#f# " 
            fixnewline="yes"> --->


            <!---   <cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = #f#>
            <cfoutput>
            <cffile action="write"
                addnewline="yes"
                file="\\squeaker\SiSystemsFile\WebServices\WebSites\Perforce\Bhargavi\report.txt" 

                output="#files.name[i]#"

                fixnewline="yes">
            </cfoutput>
                </cfloop> --->

        </body>
        </html>
```

I also have to refresh the page every 5 min but I have already done that. I need to send the `files.name` in the email.

Comment: And which part of it is giving you a problem?

Comment: i did each part separately i don't know how to add text(files.name) in  body part of the mail  instead of this "I just send this mail for testing . Please Ignore this 
"

Comment: Are my suspicions correct that you have picked up someone else's existing code, and you yourself have *no idea* how to program in CFML?

Answer (score 0):

To add files.name to your email is pretty simple.  Cfdirectory returns a query, so files is a query.  To output query results to a mail tag, simply loop through it.

```
<cfoop query="files">
#data from files#
</cfloop>
```

You'll need to add your own formatting of course.  Also note that the cfmail tag has an implicit cfoutput tag, so you don't need to add your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get all the values of any column from the cfdirectory query object using [valueList](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ValueList) or quotedValueList, without the need to loop over each one:

```
Here is the list of files:
#valueList(files.name)#
```

Comment: @DanBracuk it won't throw an error, but it's generally not needed. One specific use case is if you use the `query` and `group` attributes for `cfmail`